# Определение почтового клиента с помощью HTML

Tags: html, asp.net, email, outlook

Есть верстка письма для outlook с изображением в формате base64 а также для gmail с другим форматом для изображений.
Как определить почтовый клиент с помощью HTML? Для вывода соответствующего формата картинок под определенный почтовый клиент.

Необходимо решение в связи с тем что не работает подобный формат в outlook:

```
<img src="ссылка на изображение" onerror="this.src = 'изображение в формате base64'">
```

а также с alt, lowsrc.

И есть ли другие решения по данному вопросу?

Comment: Есть почтовый сервер([МТА](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80)), есть почтовый клиент ([MUA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0)). А кто такой почтовый менеджер, боюсь никому не известно.

Comment: Подразумеваю почтовый клиент.

Comment: Так кто об этом знает? вопрос исправляй.

Comment: Можно определить только outlook, за счёт комментариев, в остальных случаях никак, HTML в целом ничего такого делать не умеет, это всё браузер, а в почтовых клиентах этот же HTML ещё и урезан, дабы защитить пользователя и облегчить письмо.